# Do I need the @vitejs/plugin-vue dependency?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vite

I'm trying to migrate a Vue2 project from Vue-CLI/Webpack to Vite. [This migration guide](https://moiva.io/blog/the-missing-migration-guide-from-vue-cli-to-vite/#step-2-install-required-dependencies) says `@vitejs/plugin-vue` should be added as a dev dependency, but I'm not sure if I really need it, or if I do, which version I should use?

The [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/plugin-vue#readme) doesn't say much about what this plugin is for, or when it should be installed.

Answer (score 4):

`@vitejs/plugin-vue` is for **Vue 3**. You can use [vite-plugin-vue2](https://github.com/underfin/vite-plugin-vue2) for **Vue 2**.

I made a sample project with Vite, Vue2 and TailwindCSS that you can test / fork on stackblitz.

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-hu1crh